# Change Amazon Lex Chat bot Time zone

Tags: timezone, chatbot, amazon-lex

Now,I am integrating my amazon Lex chat bot to my web. I got the time zone issue. Time zone is in US East (N. Virginia). So if I say today, that is based on Virginia time. So I find how to change time zone and the suggestion is to set the x-amz-lex:time-zone request attribute to my region. but I donot know how to do and where to do. PLs help me!! Thanks.
I used simple Template `"https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-bigdata-blog/artifacts/aws-lex-web-ui/artifacts/templates/master.yaml"`.
I copied the codes from SnippetUrl and paste to my web page. The Chat Bot appear. So how should I pass these request attribute.

[this this my chat bot in amazon lex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CAP8.png)

[this is my cloud formation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9elxE.png)

[These codes are from SnippetUrl in CodeBuildDeploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhhzC.png)

Comment: To do this you need to use PostContent or PostText API. What is the current setup of your Lex bot? (User to what channel, and how does that channel connect to Lex?) If you are already using PostContent or PostText, what programming language are you using?

Comment: I have already integrated my chat bot to my website. Everything is worked except time zone. Now, I am in Singapore . If I say today, the chat bot is return the virginia usa time. I used the simple template to build my chat bot. after this, I copy the script codes and paste to my webpage. I am using ASP.net for the API and lambda function. Thanks.

Comment: The solution depends on HOW you integrated the chat bot with your website, so please show the code or explain **how you are sending the user input to Lex.** (I could type up a general answer, but you'd have to fill in the gaps to make it work with your set up, so I'm just trying to understand your set up to give you a clear answer for your case.)

Comment: Yes, I created the amazon lex bot with 2 slots (amazon date and amazon time). for the Fulfillment i used "Return parameters to client". I test and It return the date and time based on USA (virigina). after this, I used the cloud formation. the template that I used is updated in my post and then I copy the codes from SnippetUrl and paste to my web page. after this, chat bot appear in my webpage and i can use it but date time zone is based on USA. So I want to change to Singapore. So please help me sir!

Comment: This is my testing project, my main project structure is also same just different in fulfillment. In my main project, I used lambda function for fulfillment. That lambda function is write with asp.net. lambda function called the rest api that is also used asp.net mvc. That is overall flow of my project. Thanks! I also update some photos and process in my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is the solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xc54Y.png)

Finally, I got the solution. If someone want to know the solution check in the photo. I just try to fix the codes from aws github. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There may be an option in the template you are using but I can't find it, so here is what you need to know about setting timezones in Lex.

First of all, the only way to change the timezone from the default East US is to use [PostContent API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html) or [PostText API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html). They should really have a timezone setting in the Lex Console so you can set the default timezone at least, but they don't.

---

**The correct way:**

The [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tools-sdks/) is needed to use [PostContent API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html) or [PostText API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) to pass the user's input to your Lex chat bot. When passing data to Lex this way, you can include `requestAttributes` with the user's input, unique ID and session attributes (optional). Here's an example of how you would set the `timezone` in `requestAttributes` to Singapore Time:

```
{
   "inputText": "What the user said.",
   "requestAttributes": { 
      "x-amz-lex:time-zone" : "Singapore" 
   },
   "sessionAttributes": null
}
```

---

**The workaround:**

If you cannot use or cannot access the use of PostContent or PostText, then you need to work with what you have. Right now, it looks like you are only using a Lambda function for fulfillment, but you should really also use it for "initialization and validation" too.

[image]

This will pass a request to your Lambda function every time Lex processes an input and you can direct Lex with exactly how to reply. This gives you much greater control of your chat bot.

To understand the format of the Request (sometimes called "Event") and how to format the Response in that Lambda function, you will want to [read these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html).

Now, Lex processes the date and time from the user's input...(In your example, the user says "today")...and Lex will fill the date or time slots with something like (date) `2018-11-02` (time) `13:00` which will be appropriate for Eastern Standard Time (UTC -5). But Singapore is UTC +8. So you will need to convert that date and time in your Lambda function and overwrite the slots to the equivalent Singaporean time then pass those slots back in your Lambda's response to Lex.

There are multiple ways to do that conversion depending on whether your Lambda is in Node.js or Python and plenty of answers and guides on timezone conversion.

---

**Example:**

> User Input: "I want to book a meeting room from 1pm to 2pm for today"

To capture the values of this input, your Intent should be set up with something like:

> 3 slots: {date} {time_start} {time_end}
>   Intent Utterance: "I want to book a meeting room from {time_start} to {time_end} for {date}"

Lex will then parse the input and fill the slots (using timezone default: East US). Then Lex will pass the request to your "initialization and validation" Lambda Function. The request (or "event") will include:

```
{
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "BookRoom",
    "slots": {
      "date": "2018-11-05",
      "time_start": "13:00",
      "time_end": "14:00",
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Then in the Lambda Function you can take those values (Node.js):

```
var date = event['currentIntent']['slots']['date'];
var time_start = event['currentIntent']['slots']['time_start'];
var time_end = event['currentIntent']['slots']['time_end'];
```

Now for your conversion logic:
Since Singapore is 13 hours ahead of East US, just take those times and add 13 hours to them. If when doing that, it passes midnight, then also increase the date by 1 day.

This will work for inputs of *"today"*, *"tomorrow"*, *"next tuesday"*, or even *"25 Jan 2035"*, because Lex parses all of those the same way and simply delivers them to your Lambda in default East US time formatted as (date) `yyyy-mm-dd` and (time) `hh:mm`.

After you convert them, just set those slots as the new date and times, then pass the slots back to Lex in your response. Lex will then hold the slot values in Singapore time.

Comment: firstly, I really appreciate you. Thanks Jay.

Comment: My lambda function is with Asp.net. 
I think I can't do hard code like UTC +8 because There are many scenario like the user can say either today 1 pm or 5 nov 1pm .So if I do hard coded, for today will be Ok but for 5 nov 1pm it will be wrong. By the way do you know which template has option to change time zone? Thanks

Comment: I don't think there are any templates for changing timezone because they want you to do it the "correct" way. But for the workaround I explained, you don't have to worry about converting "today" or "5 nov" because Lex will do that before sending to your Lambda. Your Lambda will already receive the correct date and time formatted like I showed. You would have to then figure out the math for converting -5 to +8 in timezone, and change the date if the time change crosses over midnight.

Comment: I mean let's say I want to book a meeting room today 1pm to 2pm. I will say only "I want to book meeting room 1pm to 2pm for today". so that data will reach to my lambda and I will change to singapore time. So it will become tomorrow 1am to 2 am. Do you know what I means?. The user can say today or tomorrow or specific date. So your suggestion will be correct only for today and tomorrw not for specific date.

Comment: I've taken the case you described and expanded my answer to walk through that example, and how it will work for *any* date/time input. Because Lex parses those inputs for you, even specific dates.

Comment: Finally, I got the solution. I just try to fix in the codes from github. I will attach the solution image in the next comment. Thanks Jay for your time and suggestions.